# Verify Using the Definition of Convergence of a sequence, that the following sequences converge to the proposed limit.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

(a) lim $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} = 0$

(b) lim $\displaystyle\frac{\text{sin}(n^2)}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}} = 0$

For (a) I have:
$$\bigg|\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0\bigg| < \epsilon$$
$$n^3+3> \displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}$$
$$n^3 > \displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2} - 3$$
$$n> (\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}-3)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}}$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. The inequality $\bigg|\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0\bigg| = \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon$ is the same as $n> (\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2} -3)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}}$. Therefore, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N> (\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2} -3)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}}$. Then $\forall n \geq N$, it follows that $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \leq \frac{2N^2}{N^3+3} < \epsilon$. Thus verifying the limit.

Comment: Not correct. Second line from the end: inequality for $N$ uses undefined $n$.

Comment: i was unsure if i had to combine the $n$ terms or not. that is where my confusion lies

Comment: i have a similar problem which an $n$ term is not to the right of the inequality symbol. however, this one has two $n$ terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then see that exists $N > \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$ because no matter how big the number $2/\varepsilon$ can be we have that $\mathbb{R}$ is an [Archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) ordered field so there must be a natural number larger then $2/\varepsilon$. So this implies that  for all $n > N$ we will have

$$n > \frac{2}{\varepsilon}  \implies n + \frac{3}{n^2}> \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$$

so

$$n + \frac{3}{n^2}> \frac{2}{\varepsilon} \implies \frac{2}{n + \frac{3}{n^2}}<\varepsilon \implies \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}< \varepsilon$$

So we proved that, given an $\varepsilon > 0$ we always can find a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$ we get that

$$\left\vert\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}-0\right\vert < \varepsilon$$

For the second item the hint given above should help you.

Comment: for (a), i came across a realization that $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \leq \frac{2n^2}{n^3}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3} = \frac{2}{n} < \epsilon$ so then $n> \displaystyle\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. does that suffice?

Comment: Yes, this inequality is true. It is very important to write down correctly your answer in such a way that the line of thought be related to the definition of the limit. Every assumption that you make must be rigorously stated and justified. So that i think that this inequality _does suffice_ if you correctly use it.

Answer (score 1):

for b) we get $$\left|\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^{1/3}}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$$

Comment: since sin(x) is between $(0,1)$?

Comment: since $$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$ for all real $x$

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the second line in

> $$\bigg|\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0\bigg| < \epsilon\\
> n^3+3> \displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}$$

Follows from the first, so I believe you made a mistake there.

Comment: i am not confident in the entire soltuion i have for solving for $n$. if you have any hints or solutions to help that would be appreciated

Comment: @rover2 Yes, read my answer and notice that you made a very simple error in calculating - then re-do the whoe thing from where you made the mistake on.

Comment: so by redoing i obtain: $n > (\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{\epsilon} - 3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. but then how do i define $n$ in the inequality if i cant say $\forall n>N$?

Comment: @rover2 **Hint**: $$\frac{2n^2}{n^3+1} = \frac{2n^2}{n^3+1}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The line $n^3 + 3 > \frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}$ is wrong, it should be $n^3 + 3 > \frac{2n^2}{\epsilon}$.

(You can verify it intuitively, as when $\epsilon$ gets smaller $n$ has to get bigger, not the opposite).

Then, as pointed in the comments, you cannot make your definition of $N$ rely on $n$ and then say: for $n > N$.

Comment: can i switch the inequality to read $\displaystyle\frac{n^3+3}{2n^2} > \epsilon$?

Comment: I'm quite confused by the way you switch the inequality. How did you get there?

Comment: originally the problem gives that $\bigg|\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0\bigg|$ = $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon$

Comment: can i switch it to read $\displaystyle\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$? sorry my comment shouldve have $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$